# Issue with ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, arraylist

This code was EDITED according to advice from trutheality.

I am having trouble coming up with a good title for this one - if you have a better idea please feel free to change it.

I am creating a two dimensional ArrayList. For that I fill up an `ArrayList<String>` and then add it to `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. I do that inside a loop and I was hoping to get a fresh `ArrayList<String>` every time. This doesn't happen so `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` gets filled up with **accumulations** of `ArrayList<String>` because each time I fill up `ArrayList<String>` it just adds the what it already has.

```
ArrayList<String> oneD = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoD= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Cursor tSCursor = retrieveTS(tId);  
tSCursor.moveToFirst();

for (int i = 0; i < tSCursor.getCount(); i++) 
    {
        stockId = tSCursor.getString(tSCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

        oneD.add(sId);

        oneD.addAll(retrieveSFinParams(sId));

        twoD.add(sFinParams);           

        tSCursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

I tried sFinParams.clear() but as Java users references in the containers, when I use clear() I also loose the values in the 2D ArrayList.

How can I get a fresh ArrayList each time so when I full up the 2D ArrayList I don't duplicate the contents of the 1D ArrayList?

I appreciate any help,
D

Comment: When you make arraylists of arraylists, it means you lack a class. OOP code avoids those questions.

Comment: Did you vote it down? I wouldn't say it's a bad question, just misinformed...

Comment: Your code is a bit hard to understand (for example, what on earth is sFinParams? and where do you use your ArrayLists?). Can you give a simpler example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I use ArrayList of ArrayList because if I will create my own class  will still use some container inside a container and I don't see how I can do it better than core Java. I am willing to learn and willing to have more "class" - if you have a better solution it will be cool if you could share it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to imagine that your code was actually

```
ArrayList<String> oneD = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoD= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Cursor tSCursor = retrieveTS(tId);  
tSCursor.moveToFirst();

for (int i = 0; i < tSCursor.getCount(); i++) 
{
    stockId = tSCursor.getString(tSCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

    oneD.add(sId);

    oneD.addAll(retrieveSFinParams(sId));

    twoD.add(oneD);          

    tSCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

The problem is that you are adding the same object (`oneD`) to `twoD` repeatedly, instead of creating a new `oneD` `ArrayList` for every entry in `twoD`. The fix is simply that: create `oneD` *inside* the loop, so that every iteration works with a different `oneD`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoD= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Cursor tSCursor = retrieveTS(tId);  
tSCursor.moveToFirst();

for (int i = 0; i < tSCursor.getCount(); i++) 
{
    stockId = tSCursor.getString(tSCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

    ArrayList<String> oneD = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    oneD.add(sId);

    oneD.addAll(retrieveSFinParams(sId));

    twoD.add(oneD);          

    tSCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: Thank you trutheality - the answer is so simple :-/ I guess I shouldn't code that late at night, this often has a bad ending. Indeed you are right - the code I gave is misleading I will correct it now. I am sorry about that. Someone here even deducted some of my points for that. Thank you for making me wake up

Answer (score 3):

You must create a new instance of ArrayList at each iteration of the loop. Else, you'll keep adding elements to the same inner list, and add this unique inner list multiple times to the outer list.